# Docker: create requirements.txt in dockerfile utility container

Tags: python, docker, pip, freeze, requirements.txt

Summary: used a bind mount to populate a `requirements.txt` file using a python version I don't have locally, but the `requirements.txt` file on my local machine always remains empty.

Details:

I wanted to start a Python project using the docker hub image for Python 3.12.

I tried to use my requirements.txt file from a previous project, but the requirements.txt file is incompatible with Python 3.12.

So, I wanted to install the modern versions of the packages using Python 3.12, which I don't have on my computer. I thought I could build a utility container to:

1. install python in the container
2. install the dependencies in the container
3. create a requirements.txt file in the container
4. freeze the dependency list to the requirements.txt
5. Populate the requirements.txt on my host computer using a bind mount.

But the `requirements.txt` file remains empty. I've tried a few things, but my current dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.12.0-bookworm
WORKDIR /backend
# Install dependencies:
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pandas
<install more packages>

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "-m", "pip", "freeze", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
```

and my docker-compose file is

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  python-deps:
    working_dir: /backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: python.Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - ${PWD}/backend/requirements.txt:/backend/requirements.txt
    tty: true 
    stdin_open: true
    profiles:
      - startup-backend
```

The output of `docker-compose run python-deps` is:

```
docker-compose run python-deps
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:desktop-linux
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:desktop-linux
## The following requirements were added by pip freeze:                                                              
pandas==2.1.1
<more packages>
```

I can copy the content of the `requirements.txt` file as it's displayed in the terminal. I can paste the content into the `requirements.txt` file I have on my local machine. Then I can run other docker containers which copy that requirements.txt file. So it's useful to me in its current form :P

But, the `requirements.txt` file is empty once the container finishes.

After reading [this](https://medium.com/@jonsbun/why-need-to-be-careful-when-mounting-single-files-into-a-docker-container-4f929340834), I switched the bind mount to

```
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/backend/:/backend/`
```

but still the same issue. Any ideas on what concept/syntax I've got wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `pip freeze`, you need to redirect its output somewhere.  The [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/) `-r` option causes Pip to *read* a requirements file, rather than write one.  You can't do this using the exec (JSON-array) form of `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, but you can do this using the shell form, and particularly for this setup there's not a specific reason to avoid this.

```bash
CMD python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

---

Hopefully you have your list of dependencies written out somewhere else as well, like a [`pyproject.toml` file](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html).  (Other tools like Poetry or Pipfile would work similarly.)  To create the lock file, you fundamentally need to do three things:

1. Create a new empty virtual environment;
2. Install your package dependencies, with non-specific versions; and
3. Dump out the new lock file.

This is few enough steps that you could imagine doing it at the command line, and if this is only a one-off process then I might consider doing it with a temporary container and not a Dockerfile.  This might look like

```bash
docker run \
  --rm \
  -v "$PWD:/app" \
  -w /app
  python:3.12 \
  sh -c 'python3 -m venv /venv; /venv/bin/pip install .; /venv/bin/pip freeze > requirements.txt'
```

This runs a container, `--rm` deleting itself on completion, `-v` mounting the current directory into the container and `-w` making that directory the current directory when the container runs.  We bundle the three commands into a single `sh -c` invocation to be the one process the container runs.  The virtual environment is in a `/venv` directory in the container temporary filesystem and is deleted with the container.

Comment: Thank you so much!

This is interesting. Prior to your comment, I had tried
`ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "-m", "pip", "freeze", ">", "requirements.txt"]`
which runs normally, but doesn't populate the  file. And I had tried,
`RUN python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`, which runs oddly (opens a shell), and also doesn't populate the file. I'm still not sure why this works, but it points me to where I need to look in the docker docs. I'll read through them and report back once/if I figure it out. Will read up on the `toml` file too. Thanks again!

Comment: Initial guess is that the shell form uses shell processing and has access to the environment variables in the shell. The executable form does not do shell processing, and doesn't have access to environment variables. I think `pip freeze` is potentially accessing the environmental variables to insert the virtual environment into the requirements.txt file, causing the issue. Still gotta figure out why `RUN ...` didn't work.

Comment: I think the `RUN` version doesn't work because `RUN` is a layer creation step. The state of the container is committed to the image during the building of each layer. But, the volumes are not mounted yet because the container hasn't been initialized. So when the container is initialized, the file is potentially overwritten by the empty local file.